# Issues with Pool and multiprocessing in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

Currently I'm trying to convert my little python script to support multiple threads/cores. I've been reading about the multiprocessing module for several days now and I've also been trying to get it to suit my needs for some time, still I don't have a clue why it won't work.

[This](https://github.com/Big-Blue/MKVree/blob/db66b345fa8f2a602c538cac3ff6db7c8af01619/MKVree.py) is the working code, and [this](http://pastebin.com/vfzrHBnm) is my approach on implementing the pool workers. As there are no locks in place and I didn't want to make it too complicated at first I already disabled the logging to file.

Still it doesn't work. It doesn't even output any kind of error message. After running it it just displays the welcome message and then it just keeps running, but without outputting any of the desired output, which would be 2 lines per converted file (before + after converting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all your workers do is wait for started subprocesses to finish. they don't have any real work to do as that is performed by the external subprocesses, so they will be idle all the time.
using multiprocessing for what you do really is overkill, it's much more appropriate to use threads for that.

if you want to learn how to do multiprocessing, try something which involves inter-process communication, synchronisation, pipes, ...

but to also address your question:
hava a look at what arguments [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#subprocess.call) takes. you call it with a single space-separated command string. if you want that to work you have to pass `shell=True`, otherwise the whole string is interpreted as the executable's name.
the preferred way to call a program using subprocess is is to specify program and arguments as a list:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/program', 'arg1', 'arg2'], *otherarguments)
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer! I know that this is kind of overkill, but it might save some time when converting multiple gigs of .mkv's. Anyway, I hope I've got your hint right and tried to use Popen instead of call, using the arguments as list. Still, [this](http://pastebin.com/J9bssM1x) ends in the same way as the version with call, it just hangs after the welcome message, not outputting anything else, nor coming to an end.

Comment: no, as the python-subprocesses are just sitting there waiting for the os-subprocesses to finish, it's not going to save you any time.

Comment: I am sorry for I am feeling kind of dumb right now, not quite understanding as much as I should... What do you mean by os-subprocesses? Afaik mkvmerge/mkvtoolnix is a singlethreaded utility, so it should be one process at a time. And the python-subprocesses should - atleast in my opinion - spawn a process of mkvmerge for each subprocess, with the maximum number of parallel processes decided by cpu_cores(). Then, if one finishes, if one subprocess finished, it should get the next job/file, if there is any/are any left. But I feel like I am full of misunderstandings here. :/

Comment: the multiprocessing doesn't control the processes started using subprocess, only it's own processes. so you won't have any guarantee that your (subprocess-)started processes will run on separate cpus. here you have an [example](http://pastebin.com/Jx3mpbVd) that shows this.

Comment: also, the point was not that you shouldn't use `call`, `Popen` basically does the same, it was that you should use the right syntax to invoke it (altough I might be wrong, as it seemed to have worked before anyway - maybe there's something special going on here on windows :))

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. But to come back to the question, what shall I use to at least partly realise what I want?

Comment: I can't really say why running the program doesn't work, could be an issue with the stdout/stderr stream not being consumed (only a wild guess)... there's something about that in the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#popen-objects)

btw: [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/start-an-application-assigned-to-a-specific-cpu-in-windows-vista/) i found an example how to schedule a program to a specific cpu.